# Groovy test - unable to resolve class

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, groovy

I am writing a groovy test case in IntelliJ which uses some external java jar with Maven as the dependency manager.

Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mobicents.sipunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>sipunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The project can auto-import the needed packages and even auto-completion works when writing code but it fails to compile.

[Auto completion works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qzMU.png)

When compiling the error message below is shown

```
Error:(11, 1) Groovyc: unable to resolve class org.cafesip.sipunit.SipPhone
Error:(12, 1) Groovyc: unable to resolve class org.cafesip.sipunit.SipStack
```

I am doing the same thing with other external jars / maven dependencies but do not experience the error described above.

Comment: did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17085158/947784 ?

Comment: I just tried this, the code compiles but the solution breaks the junit groovy test. Even after changing the module > dependencies scope to provided.

Comment: Does it fail when building with maven or IntelliJ or both?

Comment: I have tried that just today. Building with Maven is successful but not in IntelliJ. Note that my main file is a groovy class. I've tried creating a java class in the same package and including the same imports and compiled it without any errors. Seems that the error only occurs in the .groovy file but not when compiling a .java file with the same imports.