# Groovy code fails to compile

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy

I have a groovy class which imports some external packages defined in the pom (maven dependency). I am using IntelliJ 2016.1.3 Community Ed, Java 1.8_92, and Groovy 2.4.6 as the global library.

I've created two classes within my project to test the problem. One is a .groovy file and one is .java.

[Classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM0U2.png)

The maven dependency is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mobicents.sipunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>sipunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Now the problem is the .groovy file throws an error during compilation while the .java does not (both use the same imports and packages). The weird thing is the groovy class can auto-import the required packages when declaring the objects which means it can "see" which packages are needed while writing the code but not during compilation.

I've been struggling with this problem for two days now. I hope someone can help.

**Imports**

```
import org.cafesip.sipunit.SipPhone
import org.cafesip.sipunit.SipStack
```

**Compilation error**

```
Error:(11, 1) Groovyc: unable to resolve class org.cafesip.sipunit.SipPhone
Error:(12, 1) Groovyc: unable to resolve class org.cafesip.sipunit.SipStack
```

As an added note, I have tried the solution here but it doesn't work.
[Groovy and IntelliJ - getting code compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084701/groovy-and-intellij-getting-code-compiled?lq=1)

Comment: Are you talking about compiling in IntelliJ, or using maven on the command-line?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I'm talking about compiling inside IntelliJ. Maven command line compiles the groovy file just fine.

Comment: So you need to reimport the project or set the classpath manually in IntelliJ.

Comment: I solved the problem by downloading the jar and putting it inside the /lib folder and adding it as a dependency. I'm not sure why having the dependency in the pom doesn't make it compile successfully. This is a really strange behavior.,